# LIKE using subquery returning multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

There 2 tables emailinfo(id,email) and keywordinfo(id,keyword).
emailinfo contains 80,000 rows and keywordinfo contains 2000 rows.

I want emails from emailinfo table which does not contains keywords from keywordinfo table.

I want not like condition on multiple rows

I have kept all keywords in keywordinfo table

Now I have to fetch all the emails from emailinfo table which not containing any keywords from keywordinfo table.

I want query like following,

```
select email 
from emailinfo 
where email not like % (select keyword from keywordinfo)
```

I have tried following query

```
SELECT email 
FROM   emailinfo
       join keywordinfo on email  like '%' + keyword +'%'**
```

but its not giving me proper results and is very slow.

Comment: Your second query will give you the emails that *do* contain keywords. For those that don't, use the NOT EXISTS query suggested by Romil below. Any query on internal substrings will likely be slow, because no indexes are useful. If certain keywords are much more common than others, there may be some ways to coax those to be checked first, but you'd have to make some design changes.

Comment: thanks for replying me.please tell me some efficient way to handle this situation,because i tried all the answer,and still it taking 2 minutes to run my query.

Comment: @UdaySatardekar, the slow speed is likely due to the database design and amount of data you're working with.

Comment: @UdaySatardekar, can you also provide a use-case for what you're attempting to do and why? Perhaps there's a better way to approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How about a slight variation of your second query...?**

```
SELECT Email 
FROM   EmailInfo
LEFT JOIN KeywordInfo ON Email LIKE '%' + Keyword + '%'
WHERE KeywordInfo.ID IS NULL
```

**Example Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #EmailInfo (ID INT, Email VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #EmailInfo (ID, Email) VALUES (1, 'test@example.com')
INSERT INTO #EmailInfo (ID, Email) VALUES (2, 'someone@sample.com')
INSERT INTO #EmailInfo (ID, Email) VALUES (3, 'testing@sample.com')
INSERT INTO #EmailInfo (ID, Email) VALUES (4, 'blahblah@blah.com')
INSERT INTO #EmailInfo (ID, Email) VALUES (5, 'example@email.com')
INSERT INTO #EmailInfo (ID, Email) VALUES (6, 'another@goodemail.com')

CREATE TABLE #KeywordInfo (ID INT, Keyword VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #KeywordInfo (ID, Keyword) VALUES (1, 'sample')
INSERT INTO #KeywordInfo (ID, Keyword) VALUES (2, 'test')

SELECT Email 
FROM   #EmailInfo EmailInfo
LEFT JOIN #KeywordInfo KeywordInfo ON Email LIKE '%' + Keyword + '%'
WHERE KeywordInfo.ID IS NULL

DROP TABLE #EmailInfo
DROP TABLE #KeywordInfo
```

Comment: No Lock is not an good idea,it will read uncommitted records. This query will return duplicate records.

Comment: @Romil, I suppose it's true that an email address could potentially match more than one keyword, but what we're showing are the records that do NOT match... so it shouldn't need a GROUP BY or DISTINCT, from what I can tell...

Answer (score 2):

The following query will returns all the records from emailinfo  table which don't have any keyword defined in keywordinfo  table.

It's advisable to have an index  on emailinfo.email fields to make the query execution faster.

```
SELECT * FROM emailinfo 
where not exists (Select 1 from
 keywordinfo where emailinfo.email like '%' + keywordinfo.keyword +'%')
```

Comment: `SELECT 1` was better than `SELECT TOP 1`

Comment: The use of TOP does nothing at all here (except make the query non-portable to SQL dialects with no TOP operator). The query optimizer knows that any single row in the correlated subquery makes NOT EXISTS false for that row. SELECT * is probably best - no expressions to parse, and inside NOT EXISTS, it is not expanded to a list of columns.

Comment: Top 1 was written by "@Photon Critical Fatal Error" who edited my answer without having knowledge of nested query with exist clause.

Comment: +1, this is about the best you can do with the existing two tables.

Comment: I'm curious whether or not this would perform better than the OUTER JOIN solution.

Comment: @Kevin, it would perform better than Outer Join because in Outer Join we will get all the records combinations matched to email content having keywords. After getting result, we can put the distinct to avoid duplicate records.

Comment: @Romil, I just did some test runs. They have nearly identical execution plans and client stats. It really just comes down to which is more readable for the OP, I guess.

Comment: The problem is the join condition, which pretty much guarantees a nested loop join.  I suspect the only real way to fix the performance problem is to normalize the key words, and have a separate process to identify which emails match which keywords when the data is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative formulation eliminates the like:

```
Select
From emailinfo ie
Where not exists (select *
           From  ki
          Where charindex(ki.keyword, ie.email) > 0)
```

I apologize for the formatting, I'm on a mobile device.

I would also recommend that you change your table structures so each keyword is in a separate row.  Then you won't need the like operator.

Comment: please tell me how i change my table stucture.because i tried all above solution but takes same amount of time.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to come up with a scenario using LIKE, have you considered using FULL TEXT INDEXING?

Pinal Dave has a fairly good introduction on it that can help get you started: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/