# SSRS SQL - Returning records based on larger strings that may contain strings from a multiple option picklist

Tags: sql, reporting-services

We have a form with a picklist with various options, and multiple options can be selected. That response gets stored as a string with the "|" character between the options.

For example - if the options are aa bb cc dd, and if someone selects aa and dd, the string 'aa | dd' is being stored.

I need to build a query where people can select multiple options as a paramter, and if any record contains any of the options selected, it should return them. So if someone selects  cc and dd, it should return records that contains things like this:

aa | cc

cc | bb

cc

dd

This works if they only select one option for the parameter, but I get an error if they select 2 options

Where TheResponse like '%' + @AllServicesRequested + '%'

I'm guessing because when 2 responses in the parameter are selected, it's stored as a table instead of a string?

I also tried putting the wildcards in the parameter field in ReportRunner for each individual option, but that didn't work either.

I also can't use IN with wildcards:

Where TheResponse in '%' + @AllServicesRequested " '%"  --this returns nothing

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're on SQL Server 2016 you can try the [split_string function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), that converts a string into a table with a column named 'value'.

```
 where exists 
 (select 1 from string_split(@AllServicesRequested,'|') where TheResponse like '%' + value + '%')
```

This was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10619049/3585500).